# Daily Popup Notification of the upcoming task within 7 days

Tags: notification, task-notifications

I have been given a task for having notification of the upcoming task in UNS bell notification popup 
1.  when  User logged in into app, then user should receive pop-up notifications for upcoming tasks that are assigned to that logged in user.
2. task notifications that have a due date within the next 7 days should enabled for the user,that user is getting notify of upcoming tasks that are assign to the user that is currently logged in, a due date within the next 7 days.

is there way to get daily notification till the due date? does it require coding or can be done from the standard salesforce options

Answer (score 0):

1. From Setup, select Object Manager.
2. Click Task.
3. Open an existing task layout or create one.
4. Add the Reminder Set field to your Task Detail section of our org’s Task page layouts.
5. Deselect Show simpler New Task form on mobile on the Activity Settings page. The simpler New Task form doesn’t include the options for creating task notifications.

** After that with a process builder you can have a time based field update depending on your reminder time and you can change it to next day until the due date.

Comment: Hi Mert ! the problem lies is that i am not allowed to add anything in the Task page Layout ..ie user can't explicitly add the reminder ....it is like if a task created today with due date 4 days later...the user should get notification for the rest of the day in between till due date is reached....if the due date is beyond 7 days ..i should get notification from 7 days prior to it.